# Software for documenting graph database nodes and edges

Tags: graphs, rdf

Starting a graph database/rdf project, I am looking for software to help with documentation.

Is there software that will create a fully editable visual/textual representation of a graph database while keeping the visual and text in sync? For example, I could edit/add new nodes to the visual, then it auto-generates text showing the node name and all of its edges. Then I edit the text, and it updates the graph visual automatically? (with .dot would be a plus)

Something like Gephi (https://gephi.org/) but with editable text explaining the nodes and edges?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going to answer my own question here.

Protégé - http://protege.stanford.edu/